# Transformation of a DataFrame Spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I want to work with a parquet table with certain types of fields:

***name_process: String id_session: String time_write: String key: String value: String***

"id_session" is a id for SparkSession.

The table is partitioned by the "name_process" column

For example:

| name_process | id_session | time_write | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OtherClass | sess000001 | 1639950466114000 | schema0.table0.csv | Success |
| OtherClass | sess000002 | 1639950466214000 | schema1.table1.csv | Success |
| OtherClass | sess000003 | 1639950466309000 | schema0.table0.csv | Success |
| OtherClass | sess000003 | 1639950466310000 | schema1.table1.csv | Failure |
| OtherClass | sess000003 | 1639950466311000 | schema2.table2.csv | Success |
| OtherClass | sess000003 | 1639950466312000 | schema3.table3.csv | Success |
| ExternalClass | sess000004 | 1639950466413000 | schema0.table0.csv | Success |

All values for the "key" column are unique only within one spark session (the "id_session" column). This happens because I work with the same files (csv) every time I start a spark session. I plan to send these files to the server. Both the time of sending and the response from the server will be recorded in the "time_write" and "value" columns.
That is, I want to see the latest sending statuses for all csv files.

This is a log for entries that I will interact with. To interact with this log, I want to implement several methods:

[image]

All getters methods will return filtered DateFrames with all columns. That is, the result remains 5 columns.
I'm still having difficulties with API Spark. It will take some time until I learn how to perform beautiful operations on DataFrames.
Here's what my result is:

```
abstract class ProcessResultBook(processName: String, onlyPartition: Boolean = true)(implicit spark: SparkSession) {

  val pathTable = new File("/src/test/spark-warehouse/test_db.db/test_table").getAbsolutePath
  val path      = new Path(s"$pathTable${if(onlyPartition) s"/name_process=$processName" else ""}").toString
  val df        = spark.read.parquet(path)


  def getLastSession: Dataset[Row] = {
    val lastTime        = df.select(max(col("time_write"))).collect()(0)(0).toString
    val lastSession     = df.select(col("id_session")).where(col("time_write") === lastTime).collect()(0)(0).toString
    val dfByLastSession = df.filter(col("id_session") === lastSession)

    dfByLastSession.show()
/*
+----------+----------------+------------------+-------+
|id_session|      time_write|               key|  value|
+----------+----------------+------------------+-------+
|alskdfksjd|1639950466414000|schema2.table2.csv|Failure|

*/
    dfByLastSession
  }

  def add(df: DataFrame) = ???
  def add(processName: String, idSession: String, timeWrite: String, key: String, value: String) = ???
  def getSessionsByProcess(processName: String) = ???
  def getBySessionAndProcess(processName: String, idSession: String) = ???
  def getUnique(processName: String) = ???
  def delByTime(time: String) = ???
  def delByIdSession(idSession: String) = ???

  def getCurrentTime: SQLTimestamp    = DateTimeUtils.fromMillis(TimeStamp.getCurrentTime.getTime)
  def convertTime(time: Long): String = TimeStamp.getNtpTime(time).getDate.toString
}
```

And I have case class:

```
case class RowProcessResult(
                              nameProcess: String,
                              idSession: String,
                              timeWrite: String,
                              key: String,
                              value: String
                           )
```

Help to implement 2 methods:

- *def add(data: List[RowProcessResult]): Unit*
- *def getUnique(nameProcess: String): DataFrame or List[RowProcessResult]*

Method *add(..)* has been added data collection in hive table.

Method *getUnique(nameProcess: String): DataFrame*. Returns a DataFrame with all columns for the unique values of the "key" column. For each unique "key" value, the most recent date is selected.

**PS.:** My test class for create Hive Table:

```
def createHiveTable(implicit spark: SparkSession) {

  val schema = "test_schema"
  val table = "test_table"
  val partitionName = "name_process"
  val columnNames = "name_process" :: "id_session" :: "time_write" :: "key" :: "value" :: Nil

  spark.sql(s"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_db")
  //val createTableSql = s"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $schema.$table ($columnNames) PARTITIONED BY $partitionName STORED AS parquet"

  val path = new File(".").getAbsolutePath ++ "/src/test/data-lineage/test_data_journal.csv"

  val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("header", true)
    .csv(path)

  df.show()

  df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy(partitionName).format("parquet").saveAsTable(s"test_db.$table")

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time. And i leave my decision this.

```
import spark.implicits._

  val schema = "test_db"
  val table  = "test_table"
  val df     = spark.read.table(s"$schema.$table").filter(col("name_process") === processName).persist


  def getLastSession: Dataset[Row] = {

    val lastSessionId   = df.select(max(struct(col("time_write"), col("id_session")))("id_session"))
                            .first.getString(0)
    val dfByLastSession = df.filter(col("id_session") === lastSessionId)
    dfByLastSession.show()
    dfByLastSession
  }

  def add(listRows: Seq[RowProcessResult]) = {

    val df = listRows.toDF().withColumn("name_process", lit(processName))
    df.show()
    addDfToTable(df)

  }

  def add(nameProcess: String, idSession: String, timeWrite: String, key: String, value: String) = {
    val df = RowProcessResult(idSession, timeWrite, key, value) :: Nil toDF()
    addDfToTable(df)
  }

  def getSessionsByProcess(externalProcessName: String) = {
    spark.read.table(s"$schema.$table").filter(col("name_process") === externalProcessName)
  }

  def getSession(idSession: String, processName: String = this.processName) = {
    if (processName.equals(this.processName))
      df.filter(col("id_session") === idSession)
    else
      getSessionsByProcess(processName).filter(col("id_session") === idSession)
  }

  def getUnique = df.sort(col("time_write").desc).dropDuplicates("key")

  def addDfToTable(df: DataFrame) =
    df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto(s"$schema.$table")

  def getFullDf = df
  def getCurrentTime = TimeStamp.getCurrentTime
  def convertTime(time: Long): String = TimeStamp.getNtpTime(time).getDate.toString
}
```

I can get tolerable solution. This is not bad. Thank you and Happy New Years!! =)